# Connecting to Object Storage on Node-Red

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, object-storage

I am trying to retrieve an image from my Object Storage service using Node-Red.

I imported the Object Storage nodes in my Node-Red instance running on IBM Bluemix and I am trying to use the "get" node but I cannot figure out how to correctly connect it to the Object Storage service.

I set the option to get the configuration details from the Bluemix Service, but when deploying I would always get an error saying "Object Storage Put (err): No object storage configuration found!".

If instead I use the option for API based configuration information, I need to fill out fields which I cannot find on my VCAP_SERVICES or the Object Storage service credentials. The fields that need to be filled in are shown

[image: here]

but my service credentials only include:

```
"apikey"
"endpoints"
"iam_apikey_description"
"iam_apikey_name"
"iam_role_crn"
"iam_serviceid_crn"
"resource_instance_id"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you bound the Object Store instance to the Node-RED app in the Bluemix console?

Comment: Yes, they are connected.

Comment: Have you restarted the Node-RED app since you bound the Object store? If so have a look in the console at the log when you set the node to use the Bluemix config options so see the logs are any more verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node-red object storage contribution available in this link:

https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-objectstore

was designed to be integrated with the Swift Object Storage in Bluemix (IBM Cloud Platform).

If you go the Catalog link below:

https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/infrastructure/object-storage-group

there are 4 options, the one you previously selected and is trying to connect is probably the first on the left side and will not integrate with node-red-contrib-objectstorage. T

To integrate with node-red you need to create an instance of the Object Storage service on the far right: Object Storage OpenStack Swift for Bluemix

Comment: Agree, but note that you need to use ProjectID for Tendant ID.  Otherwise the mapping to Credentials is clear.